# should we ask account number or card number first?

Tags: registration, banking

Should we ask about their existing card number or their existing account number for registration/open new account in banking? 
Tell the reason why you choose it!

Comment: This sounds a lot like a poll rather than a request for help with a particular problem. Are there any issues associated with choosing one or the other that you have found?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should ask for the account number first, from the simple reason that not every account necessarily have a card.
However, every client must have an account number.